# Live/Dynamic query for MongoDB NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, express

I'm making a NodeJS Express MongoDB app with the database of various books.

I have a list of books with information like Book Name, Author name, ISBN and so on.

[View of the list here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMsqF.png)

I want to create a query function such that the page finds for relevant fields as I type along in the search text field.

Any suggestions how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make text queries you can use the $text index on mongodb, and index the fields you need. this will allow you to search the text on all indexed fields.

you can read more about that here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: But how do I implement a live search?

Comment: Simply query the collection with db.colName.find( { $text: { $search: "bake coffee cake" } } )